# JxBrowser IPv6 Proxy

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I just added:

```
contextParams.setProxyConfig(new CustomProxyConfig("http=" + ip + ":" + port + ";https=" + ip + ":" + port + ";", ""));
```

but it doesn't work with IPv6 proxy. Is it a bug or IPv6 Proxy is not supported yet?

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser proxy config is provided by the Chromium engine, so IPv6 proxy is available as long as it is supported by the corresponding version of the Chromium browser.
By default, Chromium can use IPv6 if the underlying operating system supports it.